# Deploy my Gradle (Spring Boot) app in Heroku

Tags: heroku, github, gradle, spring-boot

I have a gradle + spring boot application with the following build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'teambuilting'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-docs')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

But, when I am trying to deploy my master branch in Heroku, I get the following error:

```
-----> Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/gradle.tgz
More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

I added in the Buildpacks, heroku/gradle. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

you have to define in the dashboard that the project use the buildpack for Gradle. In the build.gradle, has to add this task:

```
task stage {
    dependsOn build
}
```

and create a Procfile to indicate the next steps once heroku build your software.

Juan Antonio

Comment: Hi jabrena, what should I put in the Procfile?

Comment: You can use this example as a guide for you: https://github.com/jabrena/winter-games-game1/blob/v0.1.6/Procfile       web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar build/libs/YOUR_JAR_NAME.jar

Comment: I did what you told me, but I still have the same problem, may it be caused because I have my application in one folder? Here you have my git repo https://github.com/manuelarte/TeamBuilting.git

Comment: Yes, besides you have a folder for .openshift too. Try to move the content to root.